# Does colinearity between independent factors weaken my model?

Tags: r, random-forest, multicollinearity

I understand if a linear regression model is used colinearity is a major problem and thus my model can be weak. However, what is the case if I got a trained model with high R-squared from other algorithms such as random forest, SVM, or CART? Does colinearity between explanatory variables weaken my model?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "colinearity". Perfect colinearity (ie linear dependence) is an obvious problem since the design matrix will then not be of full rank. But if you are just referring to "high correlation" then it may not be a problem at all, unless the correlation is extremely high (say 0.9-1.0)

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not, please let us know why. Also, if you haven't already, please consider upvoting it.